# Snap all vertices to their closest grid intersection

Tags: workflow, vertices, snapping

Is there any way to snap all vertices of a given model to their closest (x,y,z) point where the grid intersects?

I know that if you activate "Snap to grid" when moving vertices they snap to the grid, but I'm asking for an automated way of snapping all of the vertices to the closest grid intersection point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can select all the vertices and choose Selection to Grid (Shift-S, 6).
helpful question because I didn't know this until now and it's useful.

[image]